# How can static_assert be used to check element type of iterator argument to templated function?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, type-traits, static-assert

I have a template for a function that takes an output iterator argument.  How can I use `static_assert` to check that an instantiation uses an appropriate iterator?  (Ie, both that it is an output iterator, and that it assigns elements of the correct type.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <set>

template <class OutputIter>
void add_ints ( OutputIter iter )
{
    static_assert ( something_goes_here,
                    "Arg must be an output iterator over ints" );

    *iter++ = 1;
    *iter++ = 2;
    *iter++ = 3;
}

main()
{
    // Insert iterator will add three elements.
    std::set<int> my_set;
    add_ints ( std::inserter ( my_set, my_set.end() ) );
    for ( int i : my_set ) std::cout << i << "\n";

    // Non-insert iterator will overwrite three elements.
    std::list<int> my_list ( { 0, 0, 0 } );
    add_ints ( my_list.begin() ) );
    for ( int i : my_list ) std::cout << i << "\n";

#if 0
    // Want nice compile error that container elements are not ints.
    std::set<std::string> bad_set;
    add_ints ( std::inserter ( bad_set, bad_set.end() ) );
#endif
#if 0
    // Want nice compile error that argument is not an iterator.
    class Foo {} foo;
    add_ints ( foo );
#endif
}
```

Comment: Use `iterator_traits<T>::value_type`. You should use `iterator_traits` for your current check to accommodate a type without a nested `iterator_category` type (not sure if that's possible for an OutputIterator). I'd also argue you should use `is_base_of` instead of `is_same` to test iterator category. Your code should still work if someone passed you a more refined iterator category that still meets all requirements of `OutputIterator` (although no such type exists in the stdlib today).

Comment: `OutputIterator`s are required to support only `*r = o`, not `r = o`. The fact that for some standard library output iterators the dereferencing operation is a no-op is an implementation detail of those iterators only, and you shouldn't rely on that in generic code. Checking for `std::output_iterator_tag` is also not a great idea in general; many mutable iterators would have a different tag.

Comment: @Praetorian That doesn't do what you want. For many `OutputIterator`s, `iterator_traits<T>::value_type` is `void`.

Comment: You can't reliably detect output iterators. The best you can do is (1) assert that the parameter is an iterator of some kind (`std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category` exists), and (2) assert it's possible to assign an integer through whatever was passed to you.

Comment: Also, having `add_ints ( my_list.end() );` assert is rather silly. A list iterator *can* be used as an output iterator just fine.

Comment: Something like `static_assert(std::is_assignable<decltype(*iter),int>(), "Jabberwocky is killing user.")` would do it.

Comment: @Casey Yes, `is_assignable` seems to work as desired.  But the need is subsumed by T.C.'s answer, which includes the element type test.

Comment: @T.C. After more reading I think I really expect the function to be called with an insert iterator.  (Does this make sense, given how I wrote my code?)  Should I edit my question to make that clear?  Also, I think all I need to do is remove the `*`s from your answer to make it check for insert iterator -- yes?

Comment: @JohnH. If you just want to check if something is a specialization of `std::insert_iterator`, you should be doing something completely different.

Comment: @T.C. I take it back, I do want an output iterator.  I edited my question in hopes of making it more concise and improving the example.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OutputIterator`s are not required to have value types; their `value_type` may well be `void`, and in fact is `void` for the purely output iterators from the standard library.

In your original question you checked for `output_iterator_tag`, but you should not. There are plenty of perfectly mutable iterators that have a different category. `std::vector<int>::iterator`'s category is `random_access_iterator_tag`, for instance.

Instead, check the well-formed-ness of the applicable expressions directly. All `Iterator`s must support `*r` and `++r`, and in addition `OutputIterator`s must support `*r = o`, `r++`, and `*r++ = o`, so:

```
template<class...>
struct make_void { using type = void; };

template<class... Ts>
using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

template<class Iter, class U, class = void>
struct is_output_iterator_for : std::false_type {};

template<class Iter, class U>
struct is_output_iterator_for<
    Iter, U, 
    void_t<decltype(++std::declval<Iter&>()),
           decltype(*std::declval<Iter&>() = std::declval<U>()),
           decltype(*std::declval<Iter&>()++ = std::declval<U>())>> : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: @T.C. If I understand, this is an improvement to my original example.  So is this how the `static_assert` in my example should be replaced?  `static_assert(is_output_iterator_for<OutputIter, OutputIter>::value, "msg");`

Comment: @JohnH. I believe it would be `static_assert(is_output_iterator_for<OutputIter, typename OutputIter::value_type>::value, "msg");`.

Comment: @0x49 The whole point is that output iterators don't have value types.  `static_assert(is_output_iterator_for<OutputIter, int>::value, "msg");`

Comment: @T.C. I rushed right in with that comment without thinking, thanks.